# Deny Delete Windows SMB fileshare - Mac OS X client

Tags: mac-osx, permissions, server-message-block

I'm struggling with this one. We have a folder within a shared drive that a certain group (group1) of users that can read/write and delete their own files and folders. However there is one account in particular (user1) that we want to be able to read/write but not delete any files (including their own). This works fine for Windows clients, but with Mac clients it comes up saying "The operation cannot be completed - you do not have sufficient privileges".

The current setup I've tried is:

- Deny - user1 - Special (Delete subfolders and files, Delete)
- Allow - user1 - Full Control
- Allow - CREATOR OWNER - Full Control
- Allow - group1 - Read & execute

All are set to Apply To: This folder, subfolders and files, except CREATOR OWNER is set to Subfolders and files only.

I appreciate any help on this.